# $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}P\left(\left(x-n\right)^{2}+\left(y-n\right)^{2}\leq n^{2}\right)$

Tags: probability

> Choose randomly $x,y$ from $S = \{0,1,\ldots , 2n\}$. $x$ and $y$ can be the same.
>   Find
>   $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}P\left(\left(x-n\right)^{2}+\left(y-n\right)^{2}\leq
>  n^{2}\right).$$

As I understood, the event $(x-n)^{2}+\left(y-n\right)^{2}\leq n^{2}$ describes a circle with center at $(n,n)$ and radius $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$. That's why I need to find the probability that square of "random" radius will be less or equal to $n^2$. Right?

How to tackle the problem then?

Comment: Right. In the limit you have a randomly chosen point from a square, and look for the probability that it is inside some circle.

Comment: The area of that square is $(2n)^2$ and of the circle, $\pi n^2$, so in the limit, $$\frac{\pi n^2}{4n^2}\stackrel{n\to\infty}\longrightarrow\frac\pi4, $$ which is consistent with @Alex R.'s answer.

Answer (score 2):

First, renormalize to give:

$$P((x/n-1)^2+(y/n-1)^2\leq 1).$$

Random variables $x/n$ and $y/n$ asymptotically approach uniform random $[0,2]$. Subtracting $1$ gives $U,V$ uniform on $[-1,1]$. It follows that you are trying to calculate:

$$P(U^2+V^2\leq 1).$$

Draw a unit square with side length 1, centered on the origin, which has area 4. This probability is equivalent to having $U,V$ fall into the circle of radius 1, giving $\pi/4$ as the limiting probability.

Answer (score 1):

By the [Gauss circle problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss_circle_problem), the number of lattice points $(x,y)$ in the circle $x^2+y^2\leq n^2$ is given by:
$$ \pi n^2 + O(n) \tag{1}$$
hence the wanted limit probability is clearly $\color{red}{\frac{\pi}{4}}\approx 78,54\%$.